# jquery file upload

Tags: php

I get the feeling I'm missing something terribly obvious with this, so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. This question specifically pertains to the jQuery file upload script found http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

I loaded this very nice and handy set of files on my server and it worked great out of the box. I'd like to enable dynamically creating user directories for users to upload files, and I've followed the directions given here: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/PHP-user-directories

I've opened up the server/php/index.php file, which contains these lines:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require('UploadHandler.php');
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler();
```

and I've edited the file to read as follows:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require('UploadHandler.php');
require('upload.class.php');

class CustomUploadHandler extends UploadHandler {
    protected function get_user_id() {
        $userid = 99771;
        return $userid;
    }
}

$upload_handler = new CustomUploadHandler(array(
    'user_dirs' => true
));
```

Obviously since this isn't live yet, I'm testing with a static user id (tested with and without quotes), but I don't see how this makes a difference. When I try running this, I get the error:
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

What could this be from? I've also tried putting the inherited class in the UploadHandler.php file instead, but I get the same error message.

Comment: It sounds like PHP is reporting an error somewhere inside of your JSON string.  Try using `error_reporting(0); ini_set('display_errors', 0);` and see if you still get that error.  You may even start getting 500 internal server errors.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I put that line in and I did get a "Internal server error". As it turns out, it did make a directory, but the directory is - well, not the directory name I specified! Instead of 99771, it's a4b4162c761187dee934cba62b5b102e, and this didn't change when I enclosed the user ID in quotes to turn it into a string literal. Why would it behave this way?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know anything about the extension you are using.  Change the source back to what it used to be and look at the JSON response string the server gets back in something like Firebug or even in your PHP logs.  You should see some kind of warning.

Comment: I got it! In the upload handler, I changed the session id to the literal value instead of trying to overwrite it in the index.php file as instructed. Works like a charm! Plus I learned something extra about JSON error reporting thanks to you Kyle.

Comment: I am glad that you were able to get it to work.  Being able to find the error reports can always be a big help.

Answer (score 0):

http://gloryplus.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=82&product_id=172

```
for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
        file = this.files[i];

        if (!!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
            if ( window.FileReader ) {
                reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = function (e) { 
                    showUploadedItem(e.target.result, file.fileName);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
            if (formdata) {
                formdata.append("images[]", file);
            }
        }   
    }

    if (formdata) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "upload.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: formdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (res) {
                document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = res; 
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain a little also?